# Blur an image without feathering the edges?

Tags: swiftui, blur, gaussianblur

I have applied a blur effect on an image which changes the value with a slider using `.blur(radius: blurAmount)`.

When I use a blur radius of around 20, the edges become transparent, which I would like to avoid. Is there a method to apply a Gaussian blur (or some other blur effect) without creating transparent edges?

Answer (score 4):

`.blur` modifier also has `opaque` parameter that is defaulted to `false`. You can set it to true like:

```swift
.blur(radius: 10, opaque: true)
```

Comment: If Opaque is default to false then the edges shouldn't be transparent already?

Setting it to true will make the effect worse than what im trying to achieve i think?

Comment: @SeanKly Have you tried? Opaque means the opposite of transparent, so when it is `false`, the edge will be transparent. Changing it to `true` will make the edge not transparent.